# Skipping :touch associations when saving an ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to **skip** updating associations with a `:touch` association when saving?

Setup:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school, touch: true
end
```

I would like to be able to do something like the following where the touch is skipped.

```
@school = School.create
@student = Student.create(school_id: @school.id)
@student.name = "Trevor"
@student.save # Can I do this without touching the @school record?
```

Can you do this? Something like `@student.save(skip_touch: true)` would be fantastic but I haven't found anything like that.

I don't want to use something like `update_column` because I don't want to skip the AR callbacks.

Comment: So you usually want to touch, but sometimes skip the touch?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Basically I have a situation where I am updating multiple models that all touch the same relation. I want to avoid the touch in that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that avoids directly monkey patching is to override the method that gets created when you have a relation with a `:touch` attribute.

Given the setup from the OP:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school, touch: true

  attr_accessor :skip_touch

  def belongs_to_touch_after_save_or_destroy_for_school
    super unless skip_touch
  end

  after_commit :reset_skip_touch

  def reset_skip_touch
    skip_touch = false
  end
end

@student.skip_touch = true
@student.save # touch will be skipped for this save
```

This is obviously pretty hacky and depends on really specific internal implementation details in AR.

Comment: Where is the definition of `belongs_to_touch_after_save_or_destroy_for_school` ?

Comment: It is defined by the `belongs_to` function. Depending on your version of Rails, you can find it somewhere like `activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb:51`

Answer (score 6):

As of Rails v4.1.0.beta1, the proper way to do this would be:

```
@school = School.create
@student = Student.create(school_id: @school.id)

ActiveRecord::Base.no_touching do
  @student.name = "Trevor"
  @student.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. `save` doesn't provide such option.

Work around this would be to have another time stamp attribute that functions like `updated_at` but unlike `updated_at`, it updates only on certain situations for your liking.