# Can I disable touch for belongs_to association temporarily when I save a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two model like this:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies
end

class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic, touch: true
end
```

When I save reply with `reply.save!`, `touch` on topic will be called and `updated_at` of topic will be updated to current time.

But sometimes I don't want to change `updated_at` automaticlly when I created a reply. So, how to disable `touch` when I save reply?

Comment: Please refer this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221586/skipping-touch-associations-when-saving-an-activerecord-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the opposite to be explicit, only touch in cases that you want to. Testing for the negative will quickly become unmanageable and could be hard to pick up by those unfamiliar with the code.

You can achieve a simple touch by calling `topic.touch`

Comment: +1 You'll be happier in the long run with less automatic, callback-based behaviors in your models. Instead try to make a single business logic method that creates a reply and handles the logic of touch-or-no-touch in one place. A lot of people now use what is known as a "service object" for this, randomly Googled article: https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question, but in case you have to skip touching records and you know what you are doing (linke in migration) you could use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.no_touching do
  Project.first.touch  # does nothing
  Message.first.touch  # does nothing
end
```

from here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NoTouching/ClassMethods.html#method-i-no_touching